# Displaying List of Objects on a DataGridView / ListView

Tags: c#, .net, list, datagridview, datasource

I have a List in a class which loads data from a .txt file, which then stores the data in objects located in another class which contains constructors and all. In my form I'm needing to display all the data in a DataGridView/ListView so i can look through it, select and make changes if needed.

However, when I come to do it on the form, nothing works, or it will just display the Constructor names at the top, yet populate no data. I've exhausted all option's, googled left right and center and seems no methods work. Tried things like DataSource = <"class">.theList. Even tried DataBindings etc. but nothing seems to work. It's giving an error like *the <"class">.theList cannot be used like a method*

Calling upon the great people of Stack OverFlow to assist me in the right direction. Thank you all in advance!

**EDIT**
I have pasted some sample code, any questions regarding it please ask away. Thankyou all.

```
public class Form{
    private void form_Load()
    {
        Wrapper wrap = new Wrapper();
        List<Child> tempList = new List<Child>();
        tempList = wrap.cList;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = tempList;
    }
}

class Wrapper{
    public List<Child> cList = new List<Child>();

    public void LoadPerson()
    {
        string filePath = @"filepath";
        //StreamReader
        //code to Add each different person + their details into the 
        protected fields
        //stores in cList variables which are in Adult
    }
}

class Adult{
    protected string username, firstName;
    protected int number;
}

class Child: Adult{

    public Child(string Username, string Password, int Number)
    {
        username = Username;
        password = Password;
        number = Number;
    }
    //public getters/setters next
}
```

Comment: Could you please assist us by providing code which you have tried so far for more understanding.

Comment: Have edited with code

Comment: `DataGridView.DataSource = listOfChilds;` - should work. Does `Child` class have properties for the fields you want to see /edit in the datagridview?

Comment: Child has the constructors, Adult has the variables

Comment: `Child` class should have public getter/setters for the fields you want to display in datagridview

Comment: Child does have them, I just wrote it as a comment "//public getters/setters" as I didn't want to paste too much code

Comment: Where you loading data to the list? In your sample Form_Load does not loading it, you just  setting empty list to the datasource.

Comment: In the Wrapper class, the .txt file containing data is StreamReader in and saved into the List, I just didn't write all the code and said it in comments instead so I didn't take up too much space

Comment: While minimizing your code here is encouraged, be careful not to omit essentials. In your example posted here, you never actually call `LoadPerson()` - which leads me to agree with Fabio that your `DataSource` is just an empty list. If that's not the case, we need to have the minimal amount of code here necessary *to reproduce the error*.

Comment: Figured the issue, for some reason I had missed loading the function to load in the data, not sure how I missed it.. Thank you all very much for your help, apologises for my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a code and data sample, it's difficult to give a good advice.

I would create a DataTable out of the data you have, in the following manner (the code needs mod according to the data structure you have constructed):

VB.NET:

```
Dim dt as New Datatable
dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))

For ir = 0 to <SRC>.rows.count -1     ' modify to which ever way you can go through your data
    dt.Rows.Add(<SRC>("ID"), <SRC>("name"))
Next

Me.DataGridView1.datasource = dt
```

C#:

```
Datatable dt = new Datatable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

for (ir = 0; ir <= <SRC>.rows.count - 1; ir++) {
    // modify to which ever way you can go through your data
    dt.Rows.Add(<SRC>("ID"), <SRC>("name"));
}

this.DataGridView1.datasource = dt;
```

Comment: And this code pasted in your question works? Tested? There's a little typo in the line "public Chil=...", so it cannot work. Anyways, do you see the expected data in the "templist" list variable, when debugging? If yes, you should be fine with changing <SRC> for templist with the provided code above and it should create a valid DataTable and fill the DataGridView.

Comment: That was just a typo when I typed it then, disregard that sorry.

Hmm I just tried then with a foreach loop to check each Child in tempList and it just skips the loop, so assuming nothing is there..

Comment: `List<T>` perfectly works as source for `DataGridView`. Converting from list to `DataTable` will be useless for this particular case.

Comment: Well I made the tempList because I tried to use the actual List<T> whilst instantiated and it said it couldn't due to it being a Collection.Generic.List

Comment: I'm sure you're right, though it was not apparent when there was no code and info in the original post. Also, it is not common to do that and I wouldn't be sure there are some hidden glitches. I'm not sure if you can see List<T> in the Object Visualizer in VS the same way you can see the content of DataTable (I suspect that it is not possible). From the practical point of view, this might ease debugging, I think.

Comment: Oh yeh I wasn't blaming you or anything, sorry if it came across that way, I should have provided code to start with (lesson learnt). Well I tried your method and replaced <SRC> with tempList but it had errors, believe it was having problems converting something with the Collection.Generic.List

Comment: No, it's Okay. To your debugging, it's difficult to say without the new code and debugging few back. I still don't know, if you checked content of the tempList? When you set a breakpoint, does it contain expected data?

Comment: Replacing `<SRC>` with `tempList` it gives the error: "Method name expected", and for the `<SRC>.rows.count` the rows doesn't work either, but just `.Count` seems to be fine

Comment: But if you set a breakpoint ať line "dataGridView1.DataSource = tempList;" and check content of the tempList, does it contain items as expected? And yes, for a list you would have to modify SRC("ID") for tempList.Items(0) and "Name" for tempList.Items(1). But using DataTable is not necessary, the point was to ease debugging, but 1st you have to check content of tempList ať runtime.

Comment: Figured the issue, for some reason I had missed loading the function to load in the data, not sure how I missed it.. Thank you very much for your help, apologises for my mistake, I will use your code to display the List<> still

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it is difficult to see what the problem could be!

But I would like to suggest another approach if you want to view objects then ObjectListView is an alternative solution.

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

It is a list view and not a datagrid view, but you can simply pass it a collection of your objects and it will show it to you.

It is also very powerful and allows you to customise a lot of things.